# Estructura Proyecto Angular5

Tags: angular-cli

estoy comenzando a usar **Angular 5** para el desarrollo de aplicaciones web, por lo que me gustaría saber cómo deben estar organizados los módulos y componentes que creamos al momento de desarrollar la aplicación.